# linq-to-sql combine expressions

Tags: linq-to-sql, lambda

Is there any way I can combine list of expressions into one? I have `List<Expression<Child, bool>> expList` and trying to combine into one (AndAlso) and get

```
Expression<Child, bool> combined = Combine(expList);
```

Intended usage for combined expression is this:

```
//type of linqFilter is IQueryable<Parent>
linqFilter = linqFilter.SelectMany(p => p.Child).
         Where(combined).Select(t=> t.Parent);
```

I am trying something like this:

```
var result = expList.Cast<Expression>().
Aggregate((p1, p2) => Expression.AndAlso(p1, p2));
```

But getting an exception

```
{"The binary operator AndAlso is not defined for the types 'System.Func`2[Child,System.Boolean]' and 'System.Func`2[Child,System.Boolean]'."}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this its a builder so you would have to recursively call it for each in expList

```
public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Combine<T>(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> first, Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> second)
{
   var toInvoke = Expression.Invoke(second, first.Parameters);

   return (Expression<Func<T, Boolean>>)Expression.Lambda(Expression.AndAlso(first.Body, toInvoke), first.Parameters);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you know why this exception btw?

Comment: The exception above ? "The binary... " ?  And is it caused by the block in the answer or in the question?

Comment: In the question - at the line above that

Comment: Thew only problem is that in the line return (Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Boolean>>(Expression.AndAlso(first.Body, toInvoke), first.Parameters)); looks like compiler cannot resolve "T". If I replace "T" with concrete type, it all works.

Comment: did u try changing Combine -> Combine<T> ?

Could have been a typo in my post(i just updated it)

Comment: Ah yeah should've noticed that. Thanks again

Comment: Can still call this method using list.Aggregate; don't have to foreach.